# How to run scheduleTime in java?

Tags: java

I have one doubt when i schedule some time it scheduling well and good. but, when it will be in when tomcat server is on.but when i am stop the server and then again running the tomcat server,at that time it is not working i.e., which is schedule previously.

for example i run my program in tomcat server and i am scheduling 10:30 AM it perform some task every day.but,i stopped the tomcat server at 10:15 AM and i again restart the server,as i told you that i schedule time at 10:30 AM to perform some task.but,i restarted server. in this case schedule time at 10:30 AM not performing the given  schedule task.

Can please any help me from this case.
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Please check timezone of tomcat server, If its not configured as per your timezone please update it.

As explicitly dealing with timezones makes your application somewhat more complex (but also more correct, less surprising, harder to test) the next best would be to explicitly make tomcat (java) know what timezone your server clock is set to. Careful: There are some levels to set this: Set your server clock to UTC, configure your server OS to be PST and then let java know of the timezone that your server is on, e.g. in setenv.sh do CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Duser.timezone=America/Los_Angeles" (or whatever your timezone is) to configure Java for your timezone.

Try this, Hope it will help you.

Comment: Doesn't look like a timezone issue. More like, stopped Tomcat, scheduled task won't run.

Comment: It could be the reason sometime because when you run server and if its not in a specific timezone then it will run after next schedule cycle and usually on local env developer would not wait for the next cycle.

Answer (score 0):

A cronjob would be the way to go, as it is immune to the status of Tomcat. Even if Tomcat is down, a cronjob would run at the right time. You might need to extract some application logic away and put it into a different jar so you can invoke it via cronjob.